# Why does my texture paint disappear from my model?

Tags: uv, texture-painting

I'm new. I drew a texture painting on a model but whenever I save it and open it in another program the texture paint disappears. I can only see the texture paint in texture paint mode. The texture paint also only appears in Solid View as well. What am I doing wrong? How do I fix this? [image]

Comment: Painted images are not saved in the blend file (if not packed) and you must use the menu Image > Save  (Alt+S) to save it. Have you done this?

Comment: I didn't pack the file the first time. I packed and saved it and it opens fine in blender, but the paint still doesn't appear when I try to view it outside of blender on 3d viewer. I'm definitely still missing something. How do I get it to appear outside of blender? edit: Is there a step I'm missing?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [.fbx export why there are no materials or textures?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/57531/fbx-export-why-there-are-no-materials-or-textures)

Comment: Yes, it does. Thank you for your help.